# How to set per category thickness in a bar chart using Chartjs?

Tags: chart.js

I have a bar chart that I need to display each category with different widths and each bar should be the width of its category. No spacing between the categories/bars. I can set `dataset.barPercentage = 1` and the bar will be the width of the category but the option `dataset.categoryPercentage` sets **ALL** categories to the same width and there is spacing between each bar.

For example, if I have 4 categories such as

1. 8/25/2023-1/31/2024 (≈92% of chart width)
2. 2/1/2024-2/6/2024 (≈2% of chart width)
3. 2/7/2024-2/11/2024 (≈2% of chart width)
4. 2/12/2024-2/21/2024 (≈4% of chart width)

The chart should then be displayed like the following where the start | and end | would be the whole width of the chart and the inner | would be the end of one bar/start of next bar.

```
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|--|--|----|
                                                1                                              2  3  4
```

Is this possible with ChartJs?

Comment: You have to set [`barThickness: 'flex'`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#barthickness) and combine with a non-category scale for x, (e.g., `type: 'linear'`, or `type: 'time'`). Here's a [basic example](https://jsfiddle.net/prtq3kjx/).